# Staying with an expired J1 visa

Tags: usa, overstaying, j1-visas

I am a French exchange student in the US. My visa expires on May 10 but I booked my plane ticket to go back home for June 14 (so a few days after the end of my 30 days grace).

Do you know what will happen if I stay with an invalid visa? Do people check it at the airport?
Do you know if I could go to Mexico by bus and return the same day with the ESTA?

Comment: If it is just your _visa_ that expires, don't worry. The visa did its job when you _entered_ the US, and its expiration date does not matter once you're inside. What should worry you is if your J-1 _immigration status_ expires before you leave, which it does _independently of the visa_.

Comment: Thank you for the info! How do I know when my immigration status expires?  And I'm also going to take a plane from California to NY before going home and while my visa is expired.. they will check my visa right?

Comment: Last I checked, neither California nor New York had seceded from the United States recently -- unless that is the case, a flight between them is a domestic flight and so does not involve _entering_ the US.

Answer (score 3):

**Visa** is the permission to enter the country. What matters is your **status**. When is the expiration date on your I-94 (it is likely electronic) or an admission stamp? If it is D/S, then when does your SEVIS record expire? It is indicated on your DS-2019. This determines when your status expires.

You will most likely be allowed to leave with an expired status. When re-entering, the fact that you overstayed makes you ineligible for the VWP.
I would suggest going to Canada and back, as departures to Mexico by land are often not recorded. Upon readmission from Canada or Mexico make sure you clearly state you intend to enter using WVP, and present your ticket back home if requested. Have a backup plan if you are denied admission.

The alternative is changing your status to that of B-1, by filing the change of status paperwork with USCIS [I-539](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/extend-your-stay). Currently, such requests [made in August 2016 are being approved](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do). However, you can stay in the country while petition is pending.

BTW, When re-entering by land, [ESTA is not required](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1258/~/esta---traveling-to-u.s.-by-land) (although having one will make your entry quicker, as you do not have to pay for and fill out an entry form)

PS. The above does not represent legal advice, and is provided just for everyone's information.

Comment: "So this route is not recommended": but the pending application will mean that the applicant does not accrue illegal presence -- does it not also allow the applicant to retain eligibility for the VWP?

Comment: correct. I thought it does not apply for B visas. Changed an answer accordingly.

Comment: My DS sas that my statues will expire at the same time: May 10. As it is very complicated for me to go to Canada (I already booked my tickets to go to CA), you think that going to Mexico by bus is useless? They don't ask for the ESTA? I don't get it, I thought it was mandatory when entering the US...

Comment: @mathz. The idea is to get out of the US before May, 10th  +grace period in a documented way. CBP does not document land departures to Mexico. One way of documenting it, is to reenter US before May, 10th +grace. So going to Mexico by bus is useful if you present yourself for reentry before May 10th + grace. Keep your bus tickets available for CBP just in case.

Comment: @mahtz, re:ESTA see the link.

Comment: @mahtz, make sure you request admission under WVP, not under your existing admission status. Canadian border is a bit more relaxed.

Comment: @mzu Thank you so so much! Yes, I'm planning on going to Mexico before the end of the grace. When you say "make sure you request admission under WVP", you mean when I apply for the ESTA online?

Comment: @mahtz, by looking at your J-1 visa, the guys from CBP may think that you are requesting admission using Automatic Visa Revalidation. You  do not want to do that. You need to say specifically, that you are requesting admission under WVP. You do not need ESTA

Comment: @mathz, the other good idea is to check with your school ISSO. They should be able to advise as well

Comment: @mathz ESTA is only required if entering by air or sea - but if you do have an ESTA, you don't Need to waste time filling out a paper form, which costs 6 Dollars (while ESTA costs 14 Dollars)

Comment: @mathz "When you say "make sure you request admission under VWP", you mean when I apply for the ESTA online?" Not when applying for the ESTA, but at the border when you present your passport

Comment: I didn't see your messages and applied for the ESTA... Was it useless then?They are not gonna give me the paper at the border?

Comment: "When re-entering, the fact that you overstayed makes you ineligible for the VWP." Source?

Comment: "It is indicated on your DS-2019. This determines when your status expires." Actually J-1 remain in status for 30 days after completing their program.